# F# - fsc.exe hangs up on huge file

Tags: f#

I run some organic chemistry models. A model is described by a generated `ModelData.fs` file, e.g.: https://github.com/kkkmail/ClmFSharp/blob/master/Clm/Model/ModelData.fs . The file has a very simple structure and using a generated model file is the only way that it can possibly work.

The referenced file is just for tests, but the real models are huge and may go close to 60 - 70 MB / 1.5M LOC. When I try to compile such files, F# compiler,`fsc.exe`, just hangs up and never comes back. It "eats" about 1.5 GB of memory and then does something forever at near 100% processing capacity. It can clearly handle smaller models, which take about 10 MB in under about a minute. So somewhere between 10 MB and 70 MB something breaks down badly in `fsc`.

I wonder if there are some parameter tweaks that I could make to the way the `fsc` compiles the project in order to make it capable of handling such huge models.

The huge models that I am referring to have one parameter set as follows: `let numberOfSubstances = 65643`. This results in various generated arrays of that size. I wonder if this could be the source of the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried breaking them up into several files?

Comment: It is a generated file. So breaking it into pieces is hard without messing up with the project file :( In addition, the failing file has many very large lists of 65,643 length. Perhaps this is the core of the problem.

Comment: There are certain thresholds that can affect how code works, some of those are: 32767 & 65535 which are the largest `int` that can be represented with 15 bits and 16 bits. Just as a test could you try with 65500 elements and if that fails with 32700. That could shed some light on the cause of the problem, which could also point to the solution.

Comment: I don't understand this. If the files are autogenerated, then why are they even required? Can't you work with whatever the source for the autogeneration was?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The generated files are effectively non-zero elements of huge very sparse matrices, which are based on some statistical distributions. So, generating them is the only way that have a decent performance. They are used by an ODE solver to perform many steps. If any transformation is used to "get" such elements at run time, then it results in a huge performance degradation.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you need to generate humongous F# source files in order to solve this, which clearly isn't a good idea even disregarding your results so far. If you generate the data in some format that your F# program can load at runtime, why would that be any less effective?

Comment: @BentTranberg I solve vector ODE problem let's say with `n` = 22767 variable (that one compiles). For each variable, I need to calculate a derivative. The derivative for each variable depends on _some_ small (in comparison to `n`) number of variables. So, I generate `n` functions: `d0 (x : array<double>) : double`, `d1`, … where `x` is the array of length `n`. The _data_ would be coefficients used inside each of those functions. Which means that I would have to sum up  each time over `n` such coefficients, most of which are identically zero. Performance then tanks 100X+ times.

Comment: @AMieres It looks that 32767 is the limit. I can always compile the files with arrays of `22767` length, _sometimes_ when the length is `27933`, and *never* when it is `33827` or above. This array length is calculated based on some parameters and cannot be varied between these numbers.

Comment: Do you know if any of the variables or parameters either in your code or the libraries you are using are of type `int16` (65535 would be possible with unit16)?. For instance do you ever need to use numbers with an `s` suffix?

Comment: @AMieres I definitely don't use `s` suffix. My guess is that since `fsc.exe` is a 32-bit application, some internal "things" there might overflow similar to how a multiplication of two large positive integers may result in a negative one. I opened a ticket with F# developers: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/6184 , though I doubt that anyone will have a look :(

Comment: It is a tough problem to solve. Good luck.

Comment: @AMieres Thanks. The idea that came to mind is that since a module is compiled into a static class, then perhaps there is a limit of how many properties can be fit into a class in NET before it blows up. I will manually split that huge file into several modules of 10K chunks (of properties / functions) each and try to compile. I will advise about the result.

Comment: You don't have to sum over `n` coefficients. If most of them are usually zero, then you can represent each function `d0`, `d1`, ... as an array or list of non-zero indices with their coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to autogenerate all of that.

From your comments, I understand that the functions `d0`, `d1`, ... are generated from a big sparse matrix in a way that sums up all of the input array `x` (with coefficients), but crucially skips summing up zero coefficients, which gives you a great performance gain, because the matrix is huge. Would that be a correct assessment?

If so, I *still* don't think you need to generate code to do that.

Let's take a look. I will assume that your giant sparse matrix has an interface for obtaining cell values, and it looks something like this:

```
let getMatrixCell (i: int) (j: int) : double
let maxI: int
let maxJ: int
```

Then your autogeneration code might look something like this:

```
let generateDFunction (i: int) =
    printfn "let d%d (x: double[]) =" i
    printfn "    [|"
    for j in 0..maxJ do
        let cell = getMatrixCell i j
        if cell <> 0 then
            printfn "        %f * x.[%d]" cell j
    printfn "    |]"
    printfn "    |> Array.sum"
```

Which would result in something like this:

```
let d25 (x : array<double>) = 
    [|
        -1.0 * x.[25]
        1.0 * x.[3]
    |]
    |> Array.sum
```

Note that I am simplifying here: in your example file, it looks like the functions also multiply negative coefficients by `x.[i]`. But maybe I'm also overcomplicating, because it looks like all the coefficients are always either `1` or `-1`. But that is all nonessential to my point.

Now, in the comments, it has been proposed that you don't generate functions `d0`, `d1`, ... but instead work directly with the matrix. For example, this would be a naive implementation of such suggestion:

```
let calculateDFunction (i: int) (x: double[]) =
    [| for j in 0..maxJ -> (getMatrixCell i j) * x.[j] |] |> Array.sum
```

You then argued that this solution would be prohibitively slow, because it always iterates over the whole array `x`, which is huge, but most of the coefficients are zero, so it doesn't have to.

And then your way of solving this issue was to use an intermediate step of generated code: you generate the functions that only touch non-zero indicies, and then you compile and use those functions.

But here's the point: yes, you do need that intermediate step to get rid of non-zero indicies, *but it doesn't have to be generated-and-compiled code*!

Instead, you can prepare lists/arrays of non-zero indicies ahead of time:

```
let indicies = 
    [| for i in 0..maxI ->
        [ for j in 0..maxJ do
            let cell = getMatrixCell i j
            if cell <> 0 then yield (j, cell)
        ]
    |]
```

This will yield an array `indicies : Array<int list>`, where each index `k` corresponds to your autogenerated function `dk`, and it contains a list of non-zero matrix indicies together with their values in the matrix. For example, the function `d22` I gave above would be represented by the 22nd element of `indicies`:

```
indicies.[22] = [ (25, -1.0), (3, 1.0) ]
```

Based on this intermediate structure, you can then calculate any function `dk`:

```
let calculateDFunction (k: int) (x: double[]) =
    [| for (j, coeff) in indicies.[k] -> coeff * x.[j] |] |> Array.sum
```

In fact, if performance is crucial to you (as it seems to be from the comments), you probably should do away with all those intermediate arrays: hundreds or thousands heap allocations on each iteration is definitely not helping. You can sum with a mutable variable instead:

```
let calculateDFunction (k: int) (x: double[]) =
    let sum = 0.0
    for (j, coeff) in indicies.[k] do
        sum <- sum + coeff * x.[j]
    sum
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like an interesting idea. And then all the coefficients can be stored in the database and loaded at run time. I need some time to try some variants along these lines and I will advise about the results.

Comment: Here is an update. I implemented the logic along the lines above. It was slightly more complicated as functions `d` are actually polynomials of up to 3rd power of the elements of `x`. The "new" way of calculations worked out of the box (thanks to F#, I guess) and provided about 2.5X performance boost for the largest array length for which I could compile the generated model (`22,767`).

Comment: Glad I could help :-)